# Towards to top and upwards

Tags: prepositions

The cave was a deep triangular fissure that gets narrower **towards the top.**

The cave was a deep triangular fissure that gets narrower **upwards**.

Would it be correct if I use “upwards” instead of “towards the top” in this sentence? If it is wrong I don’t understand why. Because as far as I see on the dictionary upwards means towards a higher point, or level. Does upwards change the meanings or is it grammatically wrong?

Comment: "...that **got** narrower..."

Answer (score 1):

"It gets narrower towards the top" means it goes up straight, then near the top it gets narrower.

"It gets narrower as it goes up" means it steadily gets narrower the farther up it goes.

"It gets narrower upwards" is bad English, but someone would probably understand it means the same as "... as it goes up".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your sentence context, "towards the top" is more commonly used.  "upwards" isn't as clear to me as an english speaker, but I don't think that it's technically wrong.